# Django - Headache on getting data with aggregate queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have been having difficulties for a while to make joints and aggregations between my models on my Django application.

For my project, I need to retrieve data in order to display them in a table.

In my application, a situation (over a certain period of time), includes a "dataserie".

These "dataserie" contain "instantdata" (value at a date).

Each "dataserie" can have a different "source" (a source from which the "instantdata" received comes).

I would like to display for a given situation (sent via the url /situation/int:primary_key), the list of the sources of the situation (thus going through the "dataserie"), and the last "instantdata" date sent by the source , in order to determine the "active" date of each source.

For example, for my situation 1, I would like to have a table of this type :

| Source | Last received date |
| --- | --- |
| Source Program1 | 02/02/2021 08:00:14 |
| Source Program2 | 02/02/2021 07:30:14 |

My model file and view file are here : https://paste.ee/p/P8M4T

Would it be even possible with query set ? Or should i use tempaltes tags in my template do to this kind of stuff ?

here are some sources i've tried to understand and implement :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

https://hakibenita.com/how-to-use-grouping-sets-in-django

https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql#how-to-sort-a-queryset-with-group-by

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Comment: Please try to post minimal code examples with your question , instead of linking to external project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is a list of source so I think you should try to make your queryset from here and add annotation like you tried :

```
sources_from_situation= Source.objects.filter(data_series__situation=situation)
sources_with_max_date = sources_from_situation.annotate(max_date=Max("data_series__instant_data__timestamp"))
for source in sources_with_max_date:
    print((str(source), source.max_date))
```

Comment: Hello ! 

Thanks for your answer, it clarified a bit.

Unfortunatelly, my source model doesn't have a direct relation with instant_data.

So, here, i have a message 
Cannot resolve keyword 'instant_data' into field. Choices are: data_serie, id, instance, type

Maybe i can go throught the relation model on dataserie ? 

Something like "Source" => "Dataserie" => "MAX(InstantData__timestamp)" ?

Comment: I think i got something 

`sources_with_max_date = sources_from_situation.annotate(max_date=Max("data_serie__instant_data__timestamp"))`

Printing the query and executing it on my SQL console gives what i want ! 

Just need to find why i got a "Source" object is not subscriptable :)

Comment: Yes that's my bad, I edited my answer. You should be able to access `max_date` directly

Comment: Holy molly ! Dam that was easy, i trully understand with the help of some `print(sources_with_max_date.query)`, viewing the SQL code is really helpfull !

Thanks man !